# Spark subtracting an integer form an arbitrary column with an unknown type

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, databricks

I am trying to take an arbitrary SQL statement as an input from one system an run it in Spark Databricks cluster.  At this point my program knows the backing tables to the SQL statement and has loaded them for the query.  But i am running into a problem where SQL allows you to subtract an integer from an arbitrary column and Spark does not.

I am try to find a way through regex to replace `(T1.SomeColumn - 1)` with its spark equivalent; without having to completely dissect the select statement to find out what table the column is coming from and what its data type is.

My question is the following: Is there a way in spark to subtract an integer from an arbitrary column of unknown type (but with the knowledge that it works in SQL)?

Comment: Could you share some code with what you have tried?

Comment: @Let'stry I have the capability of finding the data data type of the column. But it requires a lot of extra processing what i am looking for is a function that behaves like `T1.SomeColumn - 1` with out having to know the type. For example i can use regex `(CAST\s+\(.+?)(((?i)T(?-i)\d+\.\w+|\w+)(\s+[\-\+]\s+)(\d+)(\s+|\))(.+?))(\s+AS\s+)((?i)timestamp(?-i))` for subtraction in the computed column but it doesn't work when it is in the where clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subtraction operator is the same in spark as it is in normal SQL, so there is no need to replace it.

As far as subtracting arbitrary columns goes, spark has that behavior built in. Basically, spark will try to cast both columns to a number and then perform subtraction. As far as I know, strings and booleans are the only columns that can be cast to numbers. The other types will throw an exception if you try to cast them. See the example below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val df = Seq(
  (1, "name"),
  (2, "name3"),
  (3, "15"),
  (4, "73.5"),
  (5, "0.2name"),
  (6, ".7")
).toDF("num", "str")

display(
  df
    .withColumn("numMinusStr", expr("num - str"))
    .withColumn("strMinusNum", expr("str - num"))
    .withColumn("castStringAsInt", lit("hi").cast(IntegerType))
    .withColumn("castBooleanAsInt", lit(true).cast(IntegerType))
//     .withColumn("structCol", struct(lit("a").as("a"), lit(3).as("b")))
//     .withColumn("numMinusStruct", expr("num - structCol"))
//   Throws: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(`num` - `structCol`)' due to 
//   data type mismatch: differing types in '(`num` - `structCol`)' (int and struct<a:string,b:int>).
)
```

Output:
[image: Output of above code]

In the case where someone tries to subtract an integer from an arbitrary column that can't be cast to an integer, you should return the error back up the stack to whoever sent it to you, since the query isn't valid.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation seems SQL handles conversions in a more abstract way then spark SQL.  ill probably end up having to return the error to the sender then.